# Extension of $|\cdot|_\infty$ on $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$

Tags: number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $|\cdot|$ be the usual absolute value on $\mathbb C$. My question is:

> Is the only extension of $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ $|\cdot|$ itself?

I'm not sure about the uniqueness. I want to show any two extensions of $|\cdot|$ to $\mathbb C$ induce same topologies, which means that one is a positive power of the other (and so are equal).
Is it true any two absolute values on $\mathbb C$ induce the same topology (as $\mathbb C$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$)?

Thank you!

Comment: I *think* this is related to Ostrowski's Theorem. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem

"...any field, complete with respect to an archimedean absolute value, is (algebraically and topologically) isomorphic to either the real numbers or the complex numbers. This is sometimes also referred to as Ostrowski's theorem."

Comment: I think what you meant to ask was whether any two absolute values on $\mathbb{C}$ *extending* $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ induce the same topology, and then the answer is yes. For example see Gouvea's book 'p-adic Numbers', Theorem 5.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true that the usual absolute value $|\cdot|_\infty$ on $\Bbb{R}$ extends uniquely to $\Bbb{C}$, but no, it is false that *all* absolute values on $\Bbb{C}$ (or even on $\Bbb{R}$, for that matter) induce the same topology.

Here's a counterexample: with a bit of work one can prove that every $p$-adic absolute value $|\cdot|_p$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ extends (albeit non-uniquely) to an absolute value $|\cdot|_p$ on $\Bbb{C}$. Then observe that $|\cdot|_p$ cannot be equivalent to $|\cdot|_\infty$ because $|n|_p < 1$ for every $n \in \Bbb{Z}_{>0}$: in particular, every $|\cdot|_p$-ball of radius $>1$ contains the positive integers, but you can always find a positive integer outside of a $|\cdot|$-ball.

On the other hand, by one of Ostrowski's theorems we know that up to equivalence there is exactly one *Archimedean* valuation $|\cdot|_\infty$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ (you can find the proof on [PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/ProofOfOstrowskisValuationTheorem)). Now, recall that $\Bbb{R}$ can be constructed as the completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ with respect to this absolute value. By the *uniqueness* of completions, this means that $|\cdot|_\infty$ is the unique Archimedean absolute value on $\Bbb{R}$. Finally, note that $\Bbb{C} \supset \Bbb{R}$ is an algebraic extension of degree $2$ and apply the following

> **Theorem.** If $K$ is a complete field with respect to an absolute value $|\cdot|$, then $|\cdot|$ can be extended in a *unique* way to any given algebraic extension $L \supset K$. Furthermore, if $L$ is finite then $L$ is complete with respect to $|\cdot|$.
>
> *Proof.* See Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, [Theorem II.4.8](https://books.google.it/books?id=hS3qCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR7&dq=neukirch&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @petem As I said (and proved) there is indeed a unique (up to equivalence) absolute value on $\Bbb{C}$ which extends the usual absolute value $|\cdot|_\infty$ on $\Bbb{R}$. The problem is that not every possible absolute value on $\Bbb{C}$ is an extension of $|\cdot|_\infty$. Also, from Definition 5.1.1 in Gouvea's book you see that norms are defined for vector spaces over the pair $(K,|\cdot|)$, where $K$ is a complete vector field wrt $|\cdot|$.

Comment: (continued) In particular, any absolute value $|\cdot|_p$ on $\Bbb{C}$ which extends $|\cdot|_p$ on $\Bbb{Q}$ cannot give a norm on $\Bbb{C}$ as an $(\Bbb{R}, |\cdot|_\infty)$ vector space. For example, for every non-zero $\alpha \in \Bbb{C}$ we have $$|p \alpha|_p = |p|_p |\alpha|_p = p^{-1} |\alpha|_p \neq p |\alpha|_p = |p|_\infty |\alpha|_p$$

Answer (score 4):

You don't need all of Ostrowski's theorem to give that any extension of the absolute value of $\mathbb{R}$ is indeed the one used to. Here is an elementary argument. Let $||_1$ and $||_2$ be extensions of $||_{\infty}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ , where $||_1$ is the familiar extension (i.e the norm). Consider then the function $$f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
given by $f(z) = |z|_2/|z|_1.$ Then we note that since for $z= a+bi$ we have that $$|a+bi|_2 \leq |a|+|b| \leq \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \sqrt{2} |a+bi|_1$$ we have that $$|a+bi|_2/|a+bi|_1 \leq \sqrt{2}.$$ But actually, $f(\alpha) \leq 1$ for all $\alpha$ as well, since if not, since the norm is multiplicative, we'd have that for $n$ large enough that $f(\alpha^n)=f(\alpha)^n > \sqrt{2}$ which is a contradiction. Thus, we see that $|\alpha|_2 \leq |\alpha|_1.$ This shows that the two valuations give the same topology, so the restriction of them to $\mathbb{R}$ shows that they're equal.

Answer (score 3):

Any [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_(algebra)) on $\mathbf{C}$ restricting to the usual absolute value on $\mathbf{R}$ is in particular a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) on $\mathbf{C}$ as a two-dimensional real vector space. All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space induce the same topology. Thus your absolute value $|\cdot|$ on $\mathbf{C}$ restricts to a continuous homomorphism $S^1\to \mathbf{R}^+$, which must be trivial as $\mathbf{R}^+$ has no nontrivial compact subgroups, so you must have $|re^{i\theta}|=|r|$ for all $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Your previous sentence makes your argument clear, but you should be careful in saying that all norms induce the same topology. Specifically, all norms which extend the same absolute value on the base field induce the same topology.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another elementary argument that the standard absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$ is the only extension of the standard absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$:

Denote *our* absolute value by $| \cdot |$. Note that for any $z=a+bi\in \mathbb{C}$, we have $$|z| \cdot |\overline{z}| = |z \overline{z}| = |a^2 + b^2| = a^2 + b^2$$ Thus, we're done if we can prove $|z| = |\overline{z}|$. It suffices to prove this for $z\in S^1$ since any other complex number can be written as a real multiple of such $z$.

Note that $|i|^2 = |i^2| = |-1| = 1 \implies |i| = 1$. So, if $z_n = a_n + i b_n$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ with $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $$|z_n -a-bi| \le |a_n - a| + |i| |b_n - b| = |a_n - a| + |b_n - b|$$ where the right hand side converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, $z_n \to a+bi$ in the metric induced by our absolute value.

Note that if $\omega$ is a root of unity, then $|\omega| = 1$ using the relation $\omega^k = 1$ for some $k$. Given $z\in S^1$, we can choose a sequence of roots of unity $\omega_n$ such that $\omega_n \to z$ in the *standard* absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$. But, by the above argument, this implies $\omega_n \to z$ in *our* absolute value. Hence, by continuity of the absolute value, it follows $|z| = 1$.

Finally, we have for $z\in S^1$ that $|\overline{z}| = |1/z| = 1/|z| = 1 = |z|$ so we are done.

Answer (score -2):

Another elementary argument;

For roots of unity, it's clear they have norm 1. Now let $c$ be with irrational angle times pi, then take powers of it so that the angle is super close to $0$ mod $2 \cdot pi$, then use the triangle inequality in both directions its norm is close to norm $1$.

EDIT:
Since many people seem to be confused, I will add more details:

If $x$ is a root of unity of order $n$, $|x|^n=|x^n|=1$, proving $|x|=1$. In paricular this is true for $x=i$. Now let $x$ be on the unit circle, with angle $r \cdot 2pi$. Then it suffices to show that for arbitarily large $n$, $|x|^n$ is arbitarily close to $1$ (since if the norm was more than $1$, it'd explode, and if it was less, it would tend to $0$).

It is well known that if $a$ is irrational, then $na$ mod $1$ is gets arbitarily small. Applying this on our $a=r$, we find $x^n$ with $x^n-1=c+d\cdot i$ with $c$ close to $1$, and $d$ close to $0$. Then since we know $|i|=1$, subtracting $d\cdot i$ can only change the norm by $d$, so the norm is $c$ up to $+-d$, finishing the proof.